# Japanese tikz-qtree

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex, cjk, tikz-qtree, japanese

I'm having trouble using the example code from tikz-qtree to typeset a Japanese syntax tree. Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{MS Mincho}% for \rmfamily

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree-compat}
\tikzset{every leaf node/.style={font=\ja}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \Tree [ .VP [ .V\1 いる ] ]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And I get this error:

> ! Undefined control sequence.
>
> \tikz@textfont ->\ja

I am using XeLaTeX in a just-updated distribution of MiKTeX on Windows 7. Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Since you're using `xelatex`, you wouldn't need the line `\tikzset{every leaf node/.style={font=\ja}}` for font switching at all.

Comment: @LianTzeLim: When I remove that line the code compiles fine for me. You should write it up as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error tells you that the command `\ja` (presumably for font switching to Japanese) has not been defined.

But in this case, since you're using `xelatex`, you wouldn't need the line

```
 \tikzset{every leaf node/.style={font=\ja}}
```

for font switching at all. Your code should compile fine if you remove that line.